# How to configure two Couchbase source using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

How can i configure two or more couchbase data source using springboot-data-couchbase?, can anybody help me on this ?

tried this but isn't working :

[How to configure multiple couchbase data source using springboot-data-couchbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574368/how-to-configure-multiple-couchbase-data-source-using-springboot-data-couchbase)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for choosing Couchbase! Do you need to connect to two different buckets on the same cluster or to two different clusters?

Comment: @DmitriiChechetkin I need to connect with two different cluster